# C Program crashing when character is entered into menu option

Tags: c

Hi this program keeps crashing when I enter a character into the menu. I have figured out it is because scanf is looking for an integer and cannot find one so it goes into an infinite loop. I have yet to find how to correct this anywhere online and am looking for some much needed help. I cant seem to create a function to do input validation and that is where I need help as our professor does not seem to help us with these. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 void resistor (void);


 float calc_freq(float ra, float rb, float c) // function to calculate Frequency
{ 
return 1.44/((ra+(2*rb))*c);
}

float calc_duty_cycle(float ra, float rb, float c) // function to calculate duty cycle
{ 
return (rb)/(ra+(2*ra));
}

 int main (void)
{
int choice; // choice to run program from start menu or quit

while (1)
{
    // Menu for entering resistor and capacitor values
    printf("Welcome to the 555 Timer Frequency and Duty Cycle Calculator\n");
    printf("Please enter two resistor values in between ");
    printf("1 kOhms and 100 kOhms and a capacitor value\n\n");
    printf("Menu\n\n");
    printf("1. Continue\n");
    printf("2. Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", choice);
    switch (choice)
        {
            case 1: resistor();
                break;
            case 2 : printf("Goodbye.");
                break;
            default: printf("Sorry I do not understand\n\n"); 
                main();     
        
        } 
        
    break;
}

return 0;
}

void resistor (void)

{


float ra, rb, c; // Float variables for two resistor values and capacitor

while(1) // While loop to gather resistor A value
 
{

printf("Enter a value for Resistor Ra (kOhms):  "); // First Resistor Value
scanf("%f", &ra);

    if(ra < 1 || ra > 100) // Will repeat loop until value between 1 and 100 is entered
    
        printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");
        
    else
    
        break; // breaks loop when valid data is entered

}

while(1)

{

printf("Enter a value for Resistor Rb (kOhms):  "); // Second Resistor Value
scanf("%f", &rb);

    if(rb < 1 || rb > 100) // Will repeat loop until value between 1 and 100 is entered
    
        printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");
        
    else 
    
        break; // breaks loop when valid data is entered

}

while(1)

{

printf("\nCapacitor (uF) :  "); // Capacitor Value
scanf("%f", &c);
    
    if(c <= 0)
            
        printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");
    
    else 
    {
        float freq = calc_freq(ra, rb, c); // call function to calculate frequency
        float duty_cycle = calc_duty_cycle(ra, rb, c); // cal function to calculate duty cycle
        
        printf("\nFrequency is: %.2f kHz\n", freq); // print frequency
        printf("Duty cycle is: %.2f percent\n", duty_cycle*100); // print duty cycle
        
         break; // break while loop

    }
    
         
   }

 }
```

Comment: Your compiler should be warning you about `scanf("%d", choice)`. I think you mean `scanf("%d", &choice)` (pointer to choice).

Comment: For the problem you're describing I think your default case should do an `fpurge(stdin)` to clear the input so you can try again instead of re-reading the same input.

Comment: On another note, you are recursively calling main() again in the default case of the switch, which is a bad idea.  You already have a while(1) loop to prompt for input again, so you should simply break; after printing the "don't understand" message.  And the extra break statement after the switch block defeats your while loop's ability to try again, so you should remove that.